# How to keep some of the values of $_SESSION array after session_destroy()?

Tags: php, session

I use `$_SESSION` array to save the language of my website and It works fine but I found lately some problem when I log out of my website I use this code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) 
{
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: ./index.php');
}  
?>
```

So when I logout the `$_SESSION['lang']` variable is destroyed and the website language go back to default so I did this :

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) 
{
        $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;//if I echo this $_SESSION['lang'] I get the website language but after header('Location: ./index.php');  it still deleting the lang variable
        header('Location: ./index.php');
}  
?>
```

Is there something I could do it here to keep the value ???

Comment: add `session_start();` after `session_destroy();` but why don't you just save your lang param in a cookie ?

Comment: Language should not be stored in the session in the first place. It should be in the URL, so that different language versions of your content each have their own address that can be crawled, bookmarked, send to other users etc.

Comment: You will lose your lang setting once your session times out ...
This is because session is not stored forever, i suggest you to use cookies for language instead.

Answer (score 0):

Save this value in cookies(if it doesn't contains sensible information).

Comment: Why -- ?? Saving selected language in cookies instead of session is not a bad practice! It permanents active after session destroy and contains no sensitive information. It's just an advice.

Comment: This is true, session is for session data, permanent data should go to cookies.